# Threads use & to create a pointer to member

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to create multiple threads in my program and whenever I try to do this

```
std::thread thread1(threadedfunction);
```

I get this error:  `non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member`

and when I put the `&` in like this:

```
std::thread thread1(&threadedfunction);
```

I got this error: `'&': illegal operation on bound member function expression`

Comment: You need to also pass the object that the member function will act upon. Otherwise how can it know?

Comment: @PaulRooney what do you mean?

Comment: You can't call a member function without an instance of that class. For example what would `thread::join` mean without a thread instance?

Comment: Ohhhhh, so I have to call it like this std::thread thread1(&class:threadedfunction) ? and then thread1::join()

Comment: No maybe thread::join was a bad example. Let's use something different. Say class `X` has a member function `run`. You can't just call. `X::run()`. You need to do `X x; x.run();`. Where little x is the instance. If you wanted to launch this as a thread therefore you'd need to pass `x` to thread as well as the function, to give context e.g. `std::thread(&X::run, x);`

Comment: @PaulRooney thanks, I got it now.

Comment: @PaulRooney sorry for bothering you, but now I have a separate problem, I'm trying to take input and output at the same time (hence the mutlithreading) but whenever I run input in another thread, It doesn't take any input

Comment: your best bet is to ask a new question. I'm not 100% sure what you are asking, but if you can show code it would be clearer.